# OpenFire server does not work with websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, xmpp, openfire

I am not able to use OpenFire server through WebSockets. This is the code client side I use to connect to the server:

```
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://35.228.94.32:7070/ws-xmpp');

    ws.onopen = () => {
        // connection opened
        console.log('open')
    };

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
        // a message was received
        console.log(e.data);
    };

    ws.onerror = (e) => {
        // an error occurred
        console.log("Error occured", e, e.message);
    };

    ws.onclose = (e) => {
        // connection closed
        console.log("Closing: ", e);
    };
```

This is the error I receive:

> Error occured {"isTrusted": false, "message": "failed to connect to
>   /35.228.94.32 (port 7070) from /192.168.232.2 (port 54028) after
>   10000ms"} failed to connect to /35.228.94.32 (port 7070) from
>   /192.168.232.2 (port 54028) after 10000ms
>
> Closing:  {"isTrusted": false, "message": "failed to connect to
>   /35.228.94.32 (port 7070) from /192.168.232.2 (port 54028) after
>   10000ms"}

I think it is a problem of OpenFire with websockets because if I try using xmpp protocol, it works. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

Your endpoint does not seem correct. Try this instead:

```
ws://35.228.94.32:7070/ws
```

Optionally, if you want to use encryption, use:

```
wss://35.228.94.32:7443/ws
```

You will need to have set up proper certificates for that to work though.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. However, I receive the same error and nothing is changed. What do you suggest?

Comment: You were right. Beyond the port problem explained in my answer, I was wrong to use as endpoint ws-xmpp. Using ws, it works. However, can you provide me documentation where it is written the right endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem and it was not related to OpenFire. I run OpenFire on a Google Cloud machine and, by default, Google uses a firewall to block incoming requests. Hence, allowing requests to port 7070, it works.

Answer (score 0):

- just open following admin-page for openfire:

```
http://localhost:9090/index.jsp
```

- then `Server > Server Manager > Server Information > then Server Ports` :-

```
1. HTTP Binding >> for example The port used for unsecured HTTP client connections: 7071
```

- then: `ws://localhost:7071/ws`

```
2. HTTP Binding >> for example The port used for secured HTTP client connections: 7071
```

- then: `wss://localhost:7444/ws`